# Terraform: Add cloudwatch alarm to elastic load balancer generated through elastic beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I'm setting up Terraform config for an Elastic Beanstalk app that sets up an ELB. We want to have a cloudwatch alarm that triggers when the ELB gets too many 5XX errors. I'm trying to pass the ELB ARNs from the EB environment but it fails with the message:

```
value of 'count' cannot be computed
```

I know that's a common issue with Terraform, e.g. https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/10857 I can't really figure out a workaround. We're trying to make this ELB cloudwatch alarm module generic so I can't really hardcode the number of ELBs.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
locals {
  elb_count = "${length(var.load_balancer_arns)}"
}

resource aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm "panic_time" {
  count = "${local.elb_count}"
  alarm_name          = "${var.application_name}-panic-time"
  comparison_operator = "GreaterThanThreshold"
  evaluation_periods  = "1"
  metric_name         = "HTTPCode_ELB_5XX_Count"
  namespace           = "AWS/ELB"
  period              = "60"
  statistic           = "Sum"
  threshold           = "${var.max_5xx_errors}"

  dimensions {
    LoadBalancer = "${element(var.load_balancer_arns, count.index)}"
  }

  alarm_description = "SNS if we start getting a lot of 500 errors"

  alarm_actions = ["${aws_sns_topic.panic_time.arn}"]
}

resource aws_sns_topic "panic_time" {
  name = "${var.application_name}-panic-time"
}

resource aws_sns_topic_policy "panic_time" {
  arn    = "${aws_sns_topic.panic_time.arn}"
  policy = "${data.aws_iam_policy_document.panic_time_sns.json}"
}

data aws_iam_policy_document "panic_time_sns" {
  statement {
    actions = [
      "SNS:Publish",
    ]

    resources = [
      "${aws_sns_topic.panic_time.arn}",
    ]

    principals {
      type        = "Service"
      identifiers = ["events.amazonaws.com"]
    }
  }
}
```

I'm passing in the load balancers from the environment in main.tf:

```
load_balancer_arns = "${module.environment.load_balancers}"
```

(The load_balancers output looks like this:)

```
output load_balancers {
  value = "${aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment.main.load_balancers}"
}
```

Comment: Can you show the `aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment.main.load_balancers` resource? When you return the value in the output it looks like you are missing `.count`.

Comment: main.load_balancers is a list. I'm using length() to determine the count.

Comment: I assume your list you are returning is computed in some way. Can you add it to the question.

Comment: It's coming from the beanstalk environment load_balancers output: "${aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment.main.load_balancers}"

That is a default Terraform output https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/elastic_beanstalk_environment.html#load_balancers

Answer (score 0):

Didn't get how many ELB you have per environment.
I used such workaround for one ELB per environment:

```
resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment" "some-environment" {
 count = "${length(var.environments)}"
 ...
}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "alarm-unhealthy-host-count" {
 count = "${length(var.environments)}"
 ...

 dimensions {
  LoadBalancerName = "${element(aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment.some-environment.*.load_balancers[count.index], 0)}"
 }
}
```

It is funny, but I can pass any value to element(..., val), and every time I get the only correct name of ELB per environment.